# Difference of labels' node sets

Tags: neo4j

I have two labels, let's call them :Red and :Green.  All nodes under both labels have a "name" property.  I want to use Cypher to list those nodes in :Red which are not in :Green, matched by name. Any one node will either have the :Red label or the :Green label, never both.

Given these nodes:

```
(:Red {name:"One"})
(:Red {name:"Two"})
(:Red {name:"Three"})
(:Green {name:"One"})
(:Green {name:"Two"})
(:Green {name:"Five"})
```

I would like the Red-but-not-Green query to show just one node, for name="Three" because that name value appears under :Red label but not under :Green.

From my reading and experimentaion, EXISTS() requires a relationship between the nodes.  I don't want to add this just for the query and then delete it again.  `OPTIONAL MATCH` gives the desired output by returning NULL for the un-paired nodes.  Scrolling through the list will be impractical for non-trivial datasets, however.

Using Community 2.1.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create 
(:Red {name:"One"}),
(:Red {name:"Two"}),
(:Red {name:"Three"}),
(:Green {name:"One"}),
(:Green {name:"Two"}),
(:Green {name:"Five"});

MATCH (r:Red)
OPTIONAL MATCH (g:Green { name:r.name })
WITH r,g
WHERE g IS NULL 
RETURN r,g
```

see: http://console.neo4j.org/r/ya2uw8

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
MATCH (n:Red) 
WHERE NOT "Green" in labels(n)
RETURN n.name
```